# How does ruby on rails decide the Header[Content-Type] of an email in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I'm currently trying to make a mailer that sends a plain text, so I fill my content in a .txt.erb file. In this case, I assume that the Content-Type is text/plain.
If now I want to use some HTML layout as a signature, (`<%= render :partial => '/layouts/mail/signature.html.erb' %>` ), and this HTML file contains some img tag. So what is the Content-Type of this email when Rails sending it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything `.html.X` is assumed to be HTML.

The way the view filename parsing goes is by specifying type (e.g. `.html`) and then zero or more handlers, like `.erb` or `.haml`.

If you want more control over the format there's [documentation on how to do that](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-multipart-emails-with-attachments).

Comment: So if the .text.erb is the template for my email, but it renders a .html.erb partial, it will be considered as HTML when sending out?

Comment: That's normally how it works using the internal pattern matcher, but this can be configured and extended to support other types. The common ones are HTML, XML, JSON, CSV, and "plain text", though there's a bunch of others supported. I'm looking for a reference on this particular aspect but I can't find a quick summary.